# Spring cloud bus not updating config property for all instances

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I am using ***spring cloud bus*** with ***kafka*** to update the config property for multiple instances at once.
I have a cloud-config server running on localhost:8888,

**Find the below property for cloud config server :**

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=clientServer
spring.cloud.config.server.default-label=master
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/kumawatanupriya/demo-cloud-config.git
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.env.post.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
```

***Find the below dependencies used for cloud config server :***

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-monitor'
```

I am running 3 instances of **cloud-config-client** on localhost:8080, 7011, 7012.

**Find the below property for cloud config client :**

```
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.env.post.enabled=true
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled=true
spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled=true
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled=true
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled=true
spring.cloud.bus.trace.enabled=true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoAddPartitions=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
spring.profiles.active=test
```

***Find the below dependencies used for config client :***

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka"
```

I have a git repo with config file including property `inventory.initial.mode`.
When i update this property in github and hit this bus refresh endpoint `localhost:8080/actuator/busrefresh`. it only changes the value for one instances localhost:8080, it doesn't change it for 7011, 7012.
I tried hitting config-server refresh enpoint as well `localhost:8888/actuator/busrefresh`, but it also didn't update the value.

I added the monitor as well in config-server still it's not updating.
please help me identify the issue.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Removed Kafka tag since it doesn't seem related, but Kafka is not an HTTP service, so you should remove `http://` from the address

Comment: i didn't have this property spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=http://localhost:9092  in the first place,  then also it was not working.

Comment: Sure, Kafka isn't related to the problem you're having (unless somehow the cloud bus actually uses Kafka), I'm just letting you know for any future issues with that property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132836/spring-cloud-bus-not-updating-config-property-for-all-instances#new-answer I am also facing same issue , anyone suggest? @APK

Comment: @BHARATKAPSE please check this blog, might be helpful. 

https://medium.com/@anupriyakumawat95/spring-cloud-bus-dynamically-manage-and-refresh-configurations-763d22d3e419